# android app development. Is it necessary that to publish any app in play store i need to provide company domain.

Tags: android

I am new to stackoverflow as well as to android app development. I am learning to make android app and google tells me that to publish any app in play store i need to provide company domain. I don't have one. what should i do??

Comment: you are allow to select any one but intellectual properties and copyright rules must be follow...

Comment: "I don't have one" -- you need a Web site as part of your overall marketing efforts for your app. Domain names and Web hosting are available inexpensively.

Answer (score 1):

Company domain doesn't need to be an existing web domain. It's used to create your app package name. You can use `ashishagarwal.com` if you want.

Then, let's say that your app name is `myfirstapp`, your package name will be `com.ashishagarwal.myfirstapp`

The only important thing is that resulting package name is not in use by another app in the store.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Play Private Channel for Google Apps (the Private Channel) allows Google Apps domains to distribute internal Android applications to their users through the Google Play Store

**[for detail google site](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en)**